# Why does the typical magneto switch have R on the left and L on the right?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems

I can't think if I've ever seen this be done with the `L` on the left and the`R` on the right. Even on my Rotax 914, which is, *ahem*, *modern* and doesn't have magnetos, the key is still labeled with `R` on the left and `L` on the right.

[image]

Why?

Comment: I am certain that this has been asked before...

Comment: @MichaelHall I thought so, too, but hadn't found it. I'll give a more thorough look.

Comment: [Possibly related question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80868/starting-on-the-left-magneto-only-why)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This website](https://generalaviationnews.com/2022/12/28/questions-from-the-cockpit-right-vs-left/) gives a good explanation which I'll repeat here.

> But… deep breath… selecting the right-hand key position grounds out the right mag, essentially turning it off, while leaving the left mag running — so the right key position is marked with an “L.” Likewise, moving the key to the left (but not all the way to OFF) now disables the left side, leaving the right side working — hence the “R” label at the left key position.
>
> Key position dictates what’s “off,” while the label shows what’s on. So there is a certain logic to it, once you embrace it.

For a more detailed explanation see the website itself

Comment: But the "Both" and "Off" on OP's picture relate to what's on, right?

Comment: OFF means both mags are grounded out and won't work.  R means the left mag is grounded out and only the right one works. L means right mag is grounded out and only the left one works.

Comment: I read this as, "somebody crossed the wires, changed the labeling to match, and it became standard". Explains things, but doesn't make sense.

Comment: @FreeMan if I had to guess, it's because the rotary switch is the evolution of the fliip switches, http://www.avcanada.ca/forums2/viewtopic.php?p=841216&sid=f4d03657965028998c59e97ade4ff5aa#p841216. In those cases, flipping the right switch turns off the right mag. So it's a perfect mapping, although that doesn't mean it makes good sense, even if it makes sense.